# Split a time range into pieces by other time ranges in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a time range, for example: 14:30:00 until 18:30:00. Consider this time range somebody's work shift. During this time range, they state they cannot work from 15:30:00 until 16:30:00 and from 17:30:00 until 18:30:00.

```
var obj = {
startTime: 14:30,
endTime: 18:30
}

var deviation = [{s:15:30,e:16:30},{s:17:30,e:18:30}]
```

So i need output like

```
[{s:14:30 ,e:15:30}, {s:15:30,e:16:30}, {s:16:30,e:17:30}, {s:17:30,e:18:30}]
```

Comment: If it's always true that an end time follows a start time in chronological order, then you can put everything into an array, sort it, and then reassign the labels as every other one is an end time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I has created an example as you want. I think code is something tough and long so if it helpful for you then use otherwise ignore it.

```js
    var obj = {
        s: '14:30',
        e: '18:30'
    }
    var deviation = [{
            s: '15:30',
            e: '16:30'
        },
        {
            s: '17:30',
            e: '18:30'
        }]

    $(document).ready(function () {
        deviation.push(obj);
        var newArr = [];
        $(deviation).each(function (index, value) {
            newArr.push(value.e);
            newArr.push(value.s);
        });
        var newArr = newArr.sort();
        var $timeArr = [];
        lastVal = '';
        $(newArr).each(function (index, value) {

            if (index == 0) {
                lastVal = value;
            } else {
                var stTime = lastVal;
                var endTime = value;

                lastVal = endTime;
                var pushObj = {
                    s: stTime,
                    e: endTime
                }
                var lsstKey = newArr.length - 1;
                if (index != lsstKey) {
                    $timeArr.push(pushObj);
                }
            }
        });
     document.getElementById("myarray").innerHTML = JSON.stringify($timeArr);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="myarray"></p>
```

Please check in below link

https://jsfiddle.net/vinay_kaklotar/vbt1uspe/3/

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to be dynamic. `var endTime = '14:30'`. Try to make it dynamic.

Comment: var deviation = [{
            s: '15:30',
            e: '16:30'
        },
        {
            s: '16:30',
            e: '18:30'
        }], try with it, output is not correct, 16:30 to 16:30 should not come

Comment: @PrakashAbhay it's working properly. You shall check in above link of jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by concatenating your start time, end time with a sorted deviation array. Create an array from that concatenated array.

```js
var obj = {

  startTime: '14:30',
  endTime: '18:30'
}

var deviation = [{s:'15:30',e:'16:30'},{s:'16:30',e:'18:30'}]

function intervals(obj,deviation){

  // sort deviation according to starting time of deviations
  deviation.sort((a,b)=>{
    return a.s < b.s ? -1 : 1 ;
  })

  if(deviation[0].s >= obj.startTime && deviation[deviation.length - 1].e <= obj.endTime){

    let ans = [];

    ans = deviation.reduce((acc,val)=>{
      return acc.concat( val.s, val.e);
    },[]);


    // check if starttime and minimum time deviation is not same.
    if(ans[0] != obj.startTime){

      ans.unshift(obj.startTime); 
    }

    // check if endtime and maximum time in deviation is not same.
    if(ans[ans.length - 1]!=obj.endTime){

      ans.push(obj.endTime); 
    }

    let temp = [];

    // create an array of objects from sorted list ans;
    for(let i = 0; i < ans.length; i++){

      if(i+1 < ans.length){
        if(ans[i]!=ans[i+1]){
          temp.push({
            s: ans[i],
            e: ans[i+1]
          });
        }
      }
    }
    return temp;
  }
  else{
    console.log("Invalid values of deviation.");     
  }
}

console.log(intervals(obj,deviation));
```

Comment: There is one problem in it, if deviation will be var deviation = [{s:'17:30',e:'18:30'},{s:'18:30',e:'19:30'}]
then output is not correct {s:18:30,e:18:30} is extra it should not come.

Comment: can flag be added to get output like {s:17:30,e:18:30.isDeviation:true}, after splitting the time i can check value in deviation array and add the flag but is any better way to do that.

Comment: @PrakashAbhay thanks for pointing it out. I have updated my answer. Let me know if it helps.